# Custom css for bokeh widgets in one bokeh app

Tags: python, css, visualization, bokeh

is it possible to provide different css to same widget? For example, my bokeh have two select box and i want to use different css for each select box(background color bule for one select box and yellow for another). i tried to customize the css of the select box by adding following class in styles.css which is under /static/css dir. but, that css has effect on both of my select box. how can i do to get the behaviour i want? i am quite new to bokeh and hope i can get some help.
thank you!

```
.bk-root .bk-input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-height: 31px;
    padding: 0 12px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?